# is rqt_reconfigure compatible to ROS electric nodes?

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, rqt, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed camera1394 node (electric version) by source on gumstix Overo (running groovy on Linaro) and installed rqt_reconfigure on my laptop(running groovy on Ubuntu 12.04).

Everything works except I cannot use rqt_reconfigure to change the parameters dynamically.

This is the error output:

```
[ERROR] [946685833.362578387]: Client [/rqt_gui_py_node_3643] wants topic /camera1394_node/parameter_descriptions to have datatype/md5sum [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription/757ce9d44ba8ddd801bb30bc456f946f], but our version has [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription/5f0f929417f58ac7f30dfdd9e4d40ef2]. Dropping connection.
```

I noticed that rqt_reconfigure only have groovy version. Is it compatible to ROS nodes in electric version? If not, is there a trick to make it work? (It cost me a long to to build camera1394 from source, I don't want to change it to groovy version. Also, I don't know why catkin tool doesn't work in gumstix, it simply cannot find package to build).

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56223/is-rqt_reconfigure-compatible-to-ros-electric-nodes?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately these versions are going to be incompatible, which is my fault.

I changed the `dynamic_reconfigure` message definitions in order to support groups, for the main reason of making improvements to `rqt_reconfigure`. The result of this is that newer versions of `dynamic_reconfigure` are not backwards compatible, and `rqt_reconfigure` can't be used with older versions of `dynamic_reconfigure` without heavy modifications.

---

Originally posted by [klapow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2577/klapow/) with karma: 56 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-26**:
Ok, I see.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update) Not sure if this works, but you might want to give a shot to 3rd party plugin [ParamEdit](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt/Plugins#Third-party_plugins) to get a similar feature.

---

Just an isolation of the issue -- [rqt_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_reconfigure) uses [dynamic_reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) to access `parameters` and doesn't store any parameter information by itself. That said the incompatibility shouldn't occur on `rqt_reconfigure` level, and I assume it resides between `dynamic_reconfigure` and the component you're using.

I've also taken a brief look at `camera1394/cfg/Camera1394.cfg` on `groovy` but I couldn't find anything useful for this issue. I'm sure someones who are more familiar with `dynamic_reconfigure` especially on nodes sides (in this case `camera1394`) have insights.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-25**:
Thanks for your reply. It seems the message of electric version is a little bit different with the message of groovy version. I am gonna try fuerte version and see if it works.

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-25**:
Unfortunately, fuerte version also doesn't work with groovy version... I might try to install fuerte version on my laptop then.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-26**:
I poked @klapow, maintainer of `dynamic_reconfigure` to ask if he can think of anything

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-26**:
Thanks! I am gonna try ParamEdit!